# Translate "back in the day"

Tags: traducción

Consider the following sentence:

> Back in the day wheat used to be 100 dollars a ton.

Here, "back in the day" is just another way of saying something like "once upon a time" or "back then" or "there was a time when". What would be the most natural to say it in Spanish?

Off the Internet, I have noted the following alternatives:

> En aquel entonces el trigo valía cien dólares por tonelada.
>
> En ese entonces el trigo valía cien dólares por tonelada.
>
> Por antaño el trigo valía cien dólares por tonelada.
>
> En tiempos pasados el trigo valía cien dólares por tonelada.

Which of the above is the most likely one to be used by a native (Mexican, in particular) speaker? Or, is there yet another translation which is more intuitive/colloquial than the above three?

Comment: I don't think _por antaño_ is correct Spanish. Just _antaño_. The rest are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't the *exact* translation, but a good equivalent could be

> Érase una vez ...

It's usually used in the beginning of a fairy tale though, which is why most people will probably downvote this.

If you want to get literal in your translation, you could say

> Durante los antiguos tiempos ....

Which is more equivalent to

> Back in the old days

To say `Back in the day` suggests something with an indefinite duration and a *slightly* defined termination point.  Like,

> Back in the day we used to play volleyball`
>
> Back in the day cell phones didn't exist.
>
> Back in the day our dogs walked themselves.

It's the same as saying

> In the past, our dogs walked themselves

So the translation would use the imperfect

> En el pasado nuestros perros se paseaban a sí mismos.

Comment: Erase una vez means  literally "Once upon a time". Nobody would use it in that context. she's looking for "antaño" or "por aquél entonces"

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, in Spanish you could say:

> Hace tiempo el trigo valía cien dólares por tonelada
>      Tiempo atrás, el trigo valía cien dólares la tonelada

So, "back in the day" could be translated to:

> Hace tiempo [better]

Or

> Tiempo atrás

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish StachExchange! Rather than just giving translations to example sentences, we like to focus in the actual question, which in this case is the translation of “back in the day”. Then you can give example sentences that show the use of the proposed answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can say *antiguamente* too. I don't know which translation is more likely to be used by a Mexican, because I'm Chilean...

> Antiguamente, el trigo valía 100 dólares la tonelada.