# Sobre el origen de "demasiado"

Tags: etimología

Esta mañana me di cuenta de que la palabra "demasiado" se puede sustituir en muchas ocasiones por simplemente "de más". Al consultar el origen de la palabra, veo que la secuencia fue tal que así, al menos según el DLE:

> **[Más](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OWErHxJ)** >> **[demás](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C8oIUw4)** (1221) >> **[demasía](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C8qkBOT)** ('exceso', 1438) >> **[demasiado](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C8sjljP)** (adjetivo 'en exceso', 1460; adverbio 'excesivamente', 1490).

Las fechas están extraídas del diccionario etimológico abreviado de Corominas, publicado inicialmente en 1961 y revisado posteriormente en sucesivas fechas (la tercera edición es de 1973, con varias reimpresiones). Sin embargo, me pregunto qué habría sido del diccionario etimológico (y por ende del DLE, cuyas etimologías se basan mucho en el *Corominas*) si hubiese existido el CORDE [por aquel entonces](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30338/12637).

Resulta que buscando me encuentro lo siguiente:

> *Y míos hijos, debéis ser pagados cuando hubieseis tanto haber que os cumpla, ca el haber a demasiado dañoso es y lacerio muchas vegadas de aquel que lo ha, salvo ende los reyes, que lo han mester de guardar para los grandes hechos.*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro del cavallero Cifar", 1300-1305 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *[...] en que dizia commo este logar era yermo por la grande demasia queles demandauan los cogedores [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Regulación de tributos [Documentos del Reino de Castilla]", 1315 (España).

[image: Demasiado]
<sub>Ca el auer **ademasiado** dañoso es...</sub>

Resulta que no solamente los primeros de casos de *demasía* y *demasiado* son como un siglo y medio anteriores a lo estimado por Corominas, es que *demasiado* aparece antes que *demasía*, si bien es cierto que la diferencia es de apenas 10-15 años en los textos.

A juzgar por esta información, ¿es posible seguir afirmando que la secuencia que se siguió para la creación de la voz *demasiado* es la que afirma el DLE? ¿Es posible que la secuencia fuera otra y la voz *demasiado* surgiera directamente de *demás* u otra voz al mismo tiempo que *demasía*? ¿O es la palabra resaltada en la imagen otra diferente a *demasiado*?

Answer (score 1):

Aunque dice 1300-1305 (y sí esto es cuándo el original fue escrito), esa cita es de una reproducción de 2003 (Juan Manuel Cacho Blecua, Universidad de Zaragoza (Zaragoza)).

Además, ya solo existen cuatro manuscritos del *Livro del cavallero Cifar*:

- el [ms. 11.309](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=0000191780&page=64) (Biblioteca Nacional de España) del siglo XV, llamado códice M
- el [ms. espagnol 36](https://archivesetmanuscrits.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cc349700) (Biblioteca Nacional de Francia) llamado códice P o manuscrito de París, de 1464
- dos ejemplares de una edición impresa en Sevilla en 1512.

De hecho, el segundo dice esto:

> [image]
>
> ... menester de guardar para los grandes fechos, [e] gran mal es el aũ [a de] mas. E por ende [...] q̃ lo mejor de todas las cosas...

---

<sup>Otra instancia de transcripción moderna en el CORDE: [¿Por qué nos quedamos con la forma "sandio" y no con "sandío", tras siglos de coexistencia de ambas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27433/por-qu%C3%A9-nos-quedamos-con-la-forma-sandio-y-no-con-sand%C3%ADo-tras-siglos-de-co)</sup>

Comment: Partiendo de tu imagen, localizada en el [escaneo 140](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=0000191780&page=140) del enlace aportado, he visto que muy poco antes sí que se usa la palabra "demasiado" en el texto original, he incluido un escaneo y una transcripción, por lo que entiendo que la pregunta mantiene su validez. He actualizado pues la pregunta, por favor, ¿podrías actualizar la respuesta?

Comment: @Charlie no es el texto original - es un manuscrito del [siglo XV](http://bdh.bne.es/bnesearch/detalle/bdh0000191780) (y por lo tanto, las frases originales pueden haber sido editadas / actualizadas). Ya no existen ejemplos más tempranos de esta obra.

Comment: Entiendo. ¿Se le puede conceder el beneficio de la duda? Veo otros casos en el CORDE del siglo XIV: "E mas es de saber que la fabla del rey o manera de fablar a de ser conbeniente al proposito, non demasyada nin defetuosa" (1325) y "sy termjno oujesse / el fablar demasjado / que desjr non podiesse / sy non lo agujsado" (1350). Podrían ser también casos de transcripciones de copias más tardías, sí, así que voy a intentar encontrar manuscritos de la época. Ya tengo curiosidad...